# Create JVM after destroying it

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to call JNI_CreateVM after calling destroyVM but it always return -1. Is that a bug in JDK?

I found the following link that describes the same problem:
[JNI Bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HARMONY-5505)

The link has a sample code that reproduces the issue that I hace. Does anybody have an idea how to resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Sami

Comment: Is this question about the Sun JVM or about the DRLVM?

Comment: It is about Sun JVM. But this is the only link I managed to find that reproduces this issue. I reproduced it at my side and got the same result (-1 at the second createVM)

Comment: You are sure that your DestroyJavaVM call succeeded?

Comment: Yes, the returned value of destroying Java VM is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a couple of forum postings that report that CreateJavaVM / DestroyJavaVM / CreateJavaVM doesn't work; e.g.

- http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2004/Mar/msg00966.html
- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.poi.user/11742

The consensus is that DestroyJavaVM doesn't completely work due to limitations in the JVM.  Some people report that it is consistently returning -1.  Even the JNI spec hints at limitations.

There doesn't seem to be an entry in the Bug Database for this, but it could just be that Oracle has closed / deleted / hidden earlier entries.  (They seem to have been "spring cleaning" the public view of the database recently, and searches often don't work properly.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try to open an entry in the bug database and see what happens.

Comment: Don't hold your breath.  This limitation appears to have been around for a long time.

Comment: @StephenC I know this is an old question. I am facing the same problem now and I couldn't find any workaround for this. Is there anything alternative that can be done about this.

Comment: AFAIK, no there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue long time back. Here is the relevant bug entry - https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4712793

Comment: Thank you for the link. It seems that there are no plans to solve it.