# Re-loading java classpaths while JVM is up through JNI

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface

I have a C++ process that starts the JVM through JNI.

I know that I can't initialize JVM after destroying it. ([Create JVM after destroying it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149930/create-jvm-after-destroying-it)) If this could be done in any way there is no issue because I can give new classpaths and create the JVM again. Hence the JVM cannot be created after destroying I keep it up throughout my C++ process.

But I need to update the Java classpaths dynamically at the runtime as new Java files get created and compiled through my C++ process.

Is there a way to reload the Java classpaths through JNI while the JVM is up?

Comment: How about using a subprocess for the JVM, which you *can* destroy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add new classpath segments in runtime using JVM TI functions [`AddToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#AddToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch) and [`AddToSystemClassLoaderSearch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#AddToSystemClassLoaderSearch).

Comment: I see. So if I call these functions through a separate Java class which will get the classpaths from C++ it would update the JVM right?

Comment: @Will_Panda What do you mean by "through a separate Java class"? These are C functions.

Comment: I have misunderstood. Okay thanks. I'll test this and approve the answer.